# C++, checking if a variable is initialized when I can't use NULL/0

Tags: c++, null

I need to check if a variable is initialised. I am new to C++ so perhaps I am thinking about this in the wrong way. I want to do the following:

```
if (variable) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

My first thought was to set the value to NULL at declaration. However, it turns out NULL is identical to 0 in C++. Unfortunately my variable is a double that can be 0. The solutions I could find online are all regarding pointers and just say to use nullptr but this is not possible in my case of course.

What alternatives do I have here?

Comment: The compiler should tell you if you use an uninitialized variable if you set the warning level high enough.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve.  If you simply want to detect whether you've set a value for `variable`, you can initialize it with a _sentinel value_ (one that you won't ordinarily encounter), or keep a separate flag (e.g. a boolean value) to indicate whether it's initialized.  Or if this is in a loop, split out the first iteration of the loop (common for things like min/max testing).  There are other methods.  Hard to advise without a clear indication of precisely what you want to achieve.

Comment: @paddy This is what I was getting at. The value is a position in 3d space and as such both 0 and negative numbers are unavailable as a sentinel value. I could use a value like *999999999*, this is theoretically possible to get though not practically and I was going to resort to this if nothing else turned up. I also considered the flag but was wondering if something more elegant existed. While it is in a loop I am only writing a module that is called in the loop when a flag is set. I could get the loop changed but the function can be first called at any time after which it continuously runs.

Comment: Have you considered `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()`?

Comment: @paddy The programme is a flight simulator for interplanetary ships. If a user set the fuel to unlimited they could theoretically get that far but as I say it is not practically possible. When I typed *99999999* I meant the biggest number that will fit. I will probably use this if nothing else comes up.

Comment: If your var is a double, consider a `NaN` as a signalling value

Comment: for floating point NaNs are usually good sentinels. And even if NaN get slipped past checks, the result of math operation are also NaNs!

Comment: @Galik Not "should", it is "allowed to". Some compilers put sentinels into global and static ones, but automatic storage is totally unguarded. It's an UB by definition, to inspect uninitialized variable.

Comment: Coming from Typescript this is a great question! Sometimes I want a variable to be undefined.

Answer (score 4):

General way to do this is to use `std::optional`

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional

This data type wraps the inner type and provides methods to tell you if it has been set or not.

Note that you'll need a C++ 17 compiler.

Here's an example. You can see it's pretty easy to use and you don't need to create sentinel values (i.e. special values that are interpreted for the case of being not set).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <optional>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    optional<double> speed;
    if (!speed)
    {
        cout << "speed not set" << endl;
    }
    speed = 0;
    if (speed)
    {
        cout << "speed set to " << *speed << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: lacking c++17, you can probably write your own optional class that at least provides the basics of such behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge in C++ is very limited, but judging from your description I believe that you are using primitive built-in type of C++ (int, double, bool, ...). If this is the case, then it is hard to know if your variable has been initialized since the primitive type all have their default value in case it is declared but not assigned a value.

One way I used to walk around this problem is that always init the variables with special default values. However, if the variables happen to be assigned values that match the default, that could be a problem.

However, I find it rarely happen because if you are using a library, then the class should have a method/ variable... to let you know the status of the current instance if necessary. Otherwise, the class should init default valid values, or you are using it the wrong way. If you are creating your own class, then it is easy to add a status variable to it, right?

Like I said, my knowledge is very limited, I could be wrong though.